# Can't understand this line of Python code

Tags: python, regex

```
text1 = '11/27/2012'
import re
if re.match(r'\d+/\d+/\d+', text1): 
  print('YES')
```

I'm a beginner in Python.
I know a thing or two about Regular expressions in Python.. for instance : \d refers to matching 0 or more digits.

What is the above expression - line 3 - doing? More specifically, what is the significance of writing `'\d+/\d+/\d+'`?

Comment: No, `\d` refers to matching *exactly one* digit.  `\d*` would be 0 or more digits, the `\d+` you have here would be 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
text1 = '11/27/2012'
```

Sets text1 with the string value.

```
import re
```

Imports the regex module.

```
if re.match(r'\d+/\d+/\d+', text1)
```

`True` if `text1` matches the regex '\d+/\d+/\d+', otherwise `False`. The regex '\d+/\d+/\d+' describes a number containing one or more digits followed by a "/", followed by another number of one or more digits, followed by a "/", followed by yet another number of one or more digits. A date in otherwords, although it will also match "123/12345/1234567" which is not a date so there are better regex expressions for matching dates than this particular one.

```
print('YES')
```

If the previous statement is `True` print "Yes" in the console window, otherwise nothing is printed.

So this code will output YES since text1 contains a correctly formatted date in accordance with the regex. If you play around with the value stored in `text1` you can test the behaviour of the regex, i.e. test if your code outputs YES or not.